# TypeError can only convert str

Tags: python, list, typeerror

Stock = {1: {'Item Name': "Campbell's Cream of Mushroom",
             'Description': 'Canned Food',
             'Price': 2.30,
             'Stock': 32,
             'Expiry Date': '27/05/25'}}

something = []
for i in Stock:
    something.append(Stock[i]['Item Name'])
    something.append(Stock[i]['Stock'])
print(something)

x = 0
while something != ""

Comment: Hi, Can you please explain what output you are expecting. There are many errors like `x` cannot be incremented and used as index.
Is `{"Campbell's Cream of Mushroom": 32, 'Orecchiette': 23, 'Coca Cola': 25, 'Dried Cha Soba': 25, 'Chinese Cabbage': 12}` your expected output

Comment: Hi, I wanted the use it like a dictionary. E.g. {[Coca Cola, 25] ....} something along the line but i don't know how to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Stock = {1: {'Item Name': "Campbell's Cream of Mushroom",
             'Description': 'Canned Food',
             'Price': 2.30,
             'Stock': 32,
             'Expiry Date': '27/05/25'},
         2: {'Item Name': "Orecchiette",
             'Description': 'Noodles & Pasta',
             'Price': 3.45,
             'Stock': 23,
             'Expiry Date': '27/05/22'},
         3: {'Item Name': "Coca Cola",
             'Description': 'Drinks',
             'Price': 1.50,
             'Stock': 25,
             'Expiry Date': '27/05/21'},
         4: {'Item Name': "Dried Cha Soba",
             'Description': 'Noodles & Pasta',
             'Price': 3.75,
             'Stock': 25,
             'Expiry Date': '27/05/22'},
         5: {'Item Name': "Chinese Cabbage",
             'Description': "Vegetable",
             'Price': 1.50,
             'Stock': 12,
             'Expiry Date': '8/7/2020'}
         }

items = {}
for item in Stock.values():
    if item['Item Name'] in items.keys():
        items[item['Item Name']] += item['Stock']
    else:
        items[item['Item Name']] = item['Stock']


print(items)
```

Output :

> {"Campbell's Cream of Mushroom": 32, 'Orecchiette': 23, 'Coca Cola':
>   25, 'Dried Cha Soba': 25, 'Chinese Cabbage': 12}

Answer (score 0):

Firstly using `list` as a variable name is not a good idea as it is a reserved keyword in python so I've changed the name of the variable `list = []` to `something = []` and secondly you've declared `x = 0` then inside the `for loop` where you've written `for x in list:` the type of the variable `x` is getting converted to a string and that's the reason you are getting that error, So I'd suggest you to use another variable name, I've edited your code and changed it to the name `something` as mentioned above, I did a quick find a replace all and that's why the variable name `newlist` has also been changed to `newsomething`, and after resolving the error mentioned in your question your code needs further modifications but since you've not given a brief description about what's the purpose of your code, Right now I can't help you with that one. But for your current problem below is the code that I've modified.

```
Stock = {1: {'Item Name': "Campbell's Cream of Mushroom",
             'Description': 'Canned Food',
             'Price': 2.30,
             'Stock': 32,
             'Expiry Date': '27/05/25'},
         2: {'Item Name': "Orecchiette",
             'Description': 'Noodles & Pasta',
             'Price': 3.45,
             'Stock': 23,
             'Expiry Date': '27/05/22'},
         3: {'Item Name': "Coca Cola",
             'Description': 'Drinks',
             'Price': 1.50,
             'Stock': 25,
             'Expiry Date': '27/05/21'},
         4: {'Item Name': "Dried Cha Soba",
             'Description': 'Noodles & Pasta',
             'Price': 3.75,
             'Stock': 25,
             'Expiry Date': '27/05/22'},
         5: {'Item Name': "Chinese Cabbage",
             'Description': "Vegetable",
             'Price': 1.50,
             'Stock': 12,
             'Expiry Date': '8/7/2020'}
         }

something = []
for i in Stock:
    something.append(Stock[i]['Item Name'])
    something.append(Stock[i]['Stock'])
print(something)

x = 0
while something != "":
    for i in something:
        x += 1
        newsomething = something[x], something[x+1]
print(newsomething)
```